# Setting the localhost port to an environment variable

Tags: c#, asp.net, http, redirect, asp.net-web-api

Is it possible to grab the localhost port and store it into an environment variable?

I'm doing this so that I can redirect from one controller to another controller, where both controllers are in ***separate*** projects.

What I have done is this:

`return Redirect("http://localhost:12345/");`

This let's me gain access to the other controller.

However, I'm hard coding the localhost port into the **Redirect**, which I'm trying to avoid. I then thought of storing the localhost port into an environment variable in order to avoid hard coding but I'm not sure if its possible to do.

As an example, in the **launchSettings**, the **applicationUrl** is "http://localhost:123456". How do I grab this value and store this string into an environment variable?

Comment: Why can't this value be stored in the application configuration file?

Answer (score 0):

You can use environment variables or the command line to specify the host address and port the webhost will listen on. The link at https://josephwoodward.co.uk/2017/02/many-different-ways-specifying-host-port-asp-net-core has two examples at the bottom of the page.

To get the port you can use the Port property of the current uri object.

```
Uri uri = Request.Url;
string requested = uri.Scheme + Uri.SchemeDelimiter + uri.Host + ":" + uri.Port;
```